# Repeated use of a variadic function argument doesn't work

Tags: c++, c, variadic, variadic-functions

I have a function that tries to log stuff to the console and also to a log file, but it doesn't work.  The second use of the variable length argument gives garbage written to the console.  Any ideas?

```
    void logPrintf(const char *fmt, ...) {
        va_list ap;    // log to logfile
        va_start(ap, fmt);
        logOpen;
        vfprintf(flog, fmt, ap);
        logClose;
        va_end(ap);
        va_list ap2;   // log to console
        va_start(ap2, fmt);
        printf(fmt, ap2);
        va_end(ap2);
    }
```

Comment: You need to use vprintf the second time, not printf.

Answer (score 15):

The original code fails because it tries to use `printf()` where it needs to use `vprintf()`.  Taking dubious points like the `logOpen` and `logClose` statements at face value (given the notation, presumably they're macros which open and close the `flog` file stream), the code should be:

```
void logPrintf(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    logOpen;
    vfprintf(flog, fmt, ap);
    logClose;
    va_end(ap);
    va_list ap2;
    va_start(ap2, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, ap2);
    va_end(ap2);
}
```

There's no particular requirement to use two separate `va_list` variables; it is perfectly OK to use the same one twice *as long as you use `va_end()` before you use `va_start()` again.*

```
void logPrintf(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    logOpen;
    vfprintf(flog, fmt, ap);
    logClose;
    va_end(ap);
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

When a `va_list` value is passed to another function (`vfprintf()` and `vprintf()` in this code), you should assume that it is no longer usable in the current function.  It is only safe to call `va_end()` on it.

There is no need for `va_copy()` in this code.  It works, but it isn't needed.  You need `va_copy()` in other circumstances, such as when your function is passed a `va_list` and you need to process the list twice:

```
void logVprintf(const char *fmt, va_list args1)
{
    va_list args2;
    va_copy(args2, args1);
    logOpen;
    vfprintf(flog, fmt, args1);
    logClose;
    vprintf(fmt, args2);
    va_end(args2);
}
```

Note that in this code, it is the calling code's responsibility to call `va_end()` on `args1`.  Indeed, the standard says:

> Each invocation of the `va_start` and `va_copy` macros
>   shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the `va_end` macro in the same function.

Since the `logVprintf()` function doesn't call either `va_start` or `va_copy` to initialize `args1`, it cannot legitimately call `va_end` on `args1`.  On the other hand, the standard requires it to call `va_end` for `args2`.

The `logPrintf()` function can be implemented in terms of `logVprintf()` now:

```
void logPrintf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    logVprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

This structure — an operational function that takes a `va_list` and a cover function that takes ellipsis (variable arguments) and passes them to the operational function after conversion to a `va_list` — is often a good way to work.  Sooner or later, you usually find a need for the version with a `va_list` argument.

Comment: This is the correct answer that directly solves OP's question without recommending to change their architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your compiler, that is more like C++:

```
template <typename... Args>
void logPrintf(const char *fmt, Args&&... args) {
    logOpen;
    fprintf(flog, fmt, args...);
    logClose;

    printf(fmt, args...);
}
```

Though of course it would then be good taste to provide typesafe versions of `printf` and `fprintf`.

Comment: Above example requires C++11.

Comment: @DavidGiven: yes (thus the *upgrade your compiler*).

Comment: I think vfprintf needs to be fprintf instead here--you're passing the actual arguments rather than a va_list.

Answer (score -2):

I think this way makes more sense:

```
void logPrintf(const char *fmt, ...) {
        va_list ap;    // log to logfile
        va_start(ap, fmt);
        logOpen;
        vfprintf(flog, fmt, ap); //logfile
         printf(fmt, ap); //console
        logClose;
        va_end(ap);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, but that doesn't work either.  It's like the pointer gets left at the end of the list so the second use gets garbage.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what's happening. `va_list`s are always pass-by-reference.

Comment: This example (even with `vprintf` instead of `printf`) is wrong according to the man page: "If  ap is passed to a function that uses va_arg(ap,type) then the value of ap is undefined after the return of that function."  On linux x86-32 it works as intended, but not e.g. on x86-64.

Comment: This code is wrong for the reasons stated by [Armin Rigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1556290/armin-rigo) in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309246/repeated-use-of-a-variadic-function-argument-doesnt-work/9309452#comment56097427_9309341) — and, indeed, both the earlier comments.  The solution needs `va_end(ap); va_start(ap, fmt);` inserted between `vfprintf()` and `printf()`, and `printf()` needs to be replaced by `vprintf()`.  **Do not try to use this code as written.**