# Variadic function: Extract arguments and append string

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a function `log_info` (copied from `printf`'s implementation) that accepts variable no. of arguments and passes it to vprintf:

```
int log_info(const char *format, ...) {
  va_list arg;
  int done;

  va_start (arg, format);
  done = vfprintf (stdout, format, arg);
  va_end (arg);

  return done;
}
```

I want to prepend and append strings to these arguments. So if a user calls the above function this way:

```
log_info("at iteration %d, float value is %f", i, f);
```

instead of printing

```
at iteration 4, float value is 102.34
```

I want to print

```
[INFO] [at iteration 4, float value is 102.34] [timestamp: xxxx]
```

I could do it in 3 separate steps

```
fprintf(stdout, "[INFO] [");
vprintf(stdout, format, arg);
fprintf(stdout, "] [timestamp:%f]", ts);
```

But the program is multi-threaded, and hence I want all data to be written in a single call to vprintf (vprintf being thread-safe).

The other option is to lock a mutex and then write it in 3 steps as shown above, but if appending strings to the args is not too complex, I would like to try that.

Edit: Performance overhead due to use of mutex is not really an issue, but I dont want to use one unless necessary.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason you can't construct a new format string? Say with `sprintf` or `strcat`?

Comment: Be convention the timedate-stamp follows the log-level ("INFO" here), which then is followed by the log-message.

Comment: `"%f"` looks like an interesting time-stamp value btw ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to add new fields to the output, so just construct a new format string.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int loginfo(const char *format, ...) {
    int ret;
    int len;
    va_list ap;
    char *new_fmt;
    char *timestamp;
    const char fmt_template[] = "[INFO] [%s] [timestamp: %s]";

    /* Grab the timestamp now, since if we call it twice, it may change in length */
    timestamp = get_time_string();

    /* Calculate length for the augmented format string and allocate. */
    len = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt_template, format, timestamp);
    new_fmt = malloc(len + 1);

    /* Construct the new format string */
    snprintf(new_fmt, len + 1, fmt_template, format, timestamp);

    /* Print as before, using new format string */
    va_start (ap, format);
    ret = vfprintf (stdout, new_fmt, ap);
    va_end (ap);

    free(new_fmt);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. One question: why do you need `va_list ap` ?

Comment: I was keeping with C89 by declaring it at the beginning of the block. I've made the code sample complete for clarity.

Comment: I am not happy with `malloc (strlen(format) + METADATA_CHARS`. It cannot give the correct length. I think I will have to use `len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, arg);`

Comment: Assuming the timestamp is a fixed length (e.g. hh:mm:ss), then you simply have to determine the proper value for METADATA_CHARS. If it's likely to change or can't be determined, I would use `vsnprintf`. Be aware that the MSVC implementation has non-standard semantics, and returns -1 instead of the needed number of bytes if there is truncation.

Comment: Copying it to another va_list and then calculating the len sounds like a more correct way

Comment: if you would be kind enough to edit to add va_copy and len calculation, i can accept it as an answer

Comment: @KVM: The arguments are only iterated over once. The length is calculated for the format string, not the entire output, so we just need the prepended and appended strings. Edited now.

Comment: Since your `get_time_string();` function seems to return an heap allocated string, you also must free it at the end of `loginfo()`.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use vsnprintf to write the original message to a (dynamically allocated) string.  Then use fprintf to output the metadata plus original message:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
...

static const char * get_timestamp_str()
{
    ...
}

static void Log(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    int len;
    char * orig_msg;

    /* Compute length of original message */
    va_start(arg, format);
    len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, arg);
    va_end(arg);

    /* Allocate space for original message */
    orig_msg = (char *)calloc(len+1, sizeof(char));

    /* Write original message to string */
    va_start(arg, format);
    vsnprintf(orig_msg, len+1, format, arg);
    va_end(arg);

    /* Write metadata plus original message to stderr */
    fprintf(stderr, "[INFO] [timestamp %s] %s\n", get_timestamp_str(), orig_msg);
    free(orig_msg);
}
```

Comment: Good catch @Devolus, I've added the `free` now.

Comment: `vsnprintf` will consume `arg`, so `va_copy` should be used to copy it to a second va_list before the call.

Comment: @jared_schmitz: The second va_start will re-initialize arg, correct?

Comment: @GregPrisament: No. It probably will on most major systems. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309246/repeated-use-of-a-variadic-function-argument-doesnt-work

Comment: @jared_schmitz:  Beg to differ.  The man page for "va_end" states: "Each invocation of va_start() must be matched by a corresponding invocation of va_end() in the same function.  After the call va_end(ap) the variable ap is undefined.  Multiple traversals of the list, each bracketed by va_start() and va_end() are possible."

Comment: @jared_schmitz: Makes me wonder what's going on in that question you linked to...