# why called function can get arguments of parent-function by va_start()?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gcc

I implemented a function with variable arguments below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define ERR_BUFFER_SIZE 4096

void errPrint(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, format);

    char buf[ERR_BUFFER_SIZE];
    vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), format, argptr);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", buf);
    
    va_end(argptr);
}
```

Then I hope to implement another named "errExit()" based on the function above.
I just tried like below.It works as I hoped but I dont't think it correct.

```c
void errExit(const char *format, ...)
{
    errPrint(format);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I tried `errExit("hello,%s,%s,%s", "arg1","arg2", "arg3");` and it printed "`hello,arg1,arg2,arg3`" correctly.

But after I added two line code like below, it throwed error `Segmentation fault`.

```c
void errExit(const char *format, ...)
{
    char buf[4096];//added
    strcpy(buf, format);//added
    
    errPrint(format);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I am very confused.
According to what I learned：

1. There is only one argument `format` in the stack of called function `errPrint()`. I can't believe `va_start()` will get arguments from the its parent-function `errExit()`.
2. Since `errPrint()` works "correctly", why it doesn't work after I add the two lines code? It seems that the code added have no effect.

(My English is not well, hoping you everyone can stand my statement. Thank you! )

Comment: You probably want to create another function, `verrPrint(const char *format, va_list ap)` then call that function in `errExit()`.  Then refactor `errPrint(const char *format, ...)` to to call `verrPrint()`.

Comment: See also [Repeated use of a variadic function argument doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41411702/15168), which outlines that you often need a pair of functions, one taking ellipsis `, ...)` and the other taking a `va_list args)` at the end of the argument list, as suggested in the oldest answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers explain what you need to do.  This answer is about the asm details of why it happened to work.

---

In your first `errExit`, if you look at the compiler-generated assembly for x86-64, all the incoming args would still be in registers when calling `errPrint(format);`.  Even though you don't tell the compiler to pass them, it doesn't do anything that uses registers before calling that other function.

So it **happens to work** even though you didn't explicitly pass along any args beyond the first (`format`).  It compiles *as if* you'd written a function that passed along its first 6 args, assuming the x86-64 System V calling convention, and that the args were all integer or pointer (such as `char*`).

In the C abstract machine, your code is meaningless and has undefined behaviour when `errPrint` makes a `va_list argptr` and passes it on to a function (`vsnprintf`) that references more than 0 elements of that list.

It might help to look at asm for a function that does pass on multiple args:

```c
void foo(char *a, char *b, char *c, char *d, char *f);
int  bar(char *a, char *b, char *c, char *d, char *f)
{
    foo(a, b, c, d, f);
    return 1;   // some code after the call, so it can't compile to a tailcall
}
```

[On Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:13,endLineNumber:30,positionColumn:13,positionLineNumber:30,selectionStartColumn:13,selectionStartLineNumber:30,startColumn:13,startLineNumber:30),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdarg.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+ERR_BUFFER_SIZE+4096%0A%0Avoid+errPrint(const+char+*format,+...)%0A%7B%0A++++va_list+argptr%3B%0A++++va_start(argptr,+format)%3B%0A%0A++++char+buf%5BERR_BUFFER_SIZE%5D%3B%0A++++vsnprintf(buf,+sizeof(buf),+format,+argptr)%3B%0A++++fprintf(stderr,+%22%25s%22,+buf)%3B%0A++++%0A++++va_end(argptr)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+errExit(const+char+*format,+...)%0A%7B%0A++++errPrint(format)%3B%0A++++exit(EXIT_FAILURE)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+foo(int+a,+int+b,+int+c,+int+d,+int+f)%3B%0Aint+bar(int+a,+int+b,+int+c,+int+d,+int+f)%0A%7B%0A++++foo(a,+b,+c,+d,+f)%3B%0A++++return+1%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:51.42463235294118,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg122,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.575367647058826,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), compiling for Linux with GCC12:

```
# GCC12 -O3
bar:
    # incoming args are in RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9  in that order
    # same place a callee will look for them, so passing them on is trivial
        sub     rsp, 8        # re-align the stack so RSP%16 == 0
        call    foo
        mov     eax, 1        # return-value register = 1
        add     rsp, 8        # restore the stack pointer
        ret                   # pop return address into RIP
```

Your `errExit` has equivalent asm before the call, so if there are register args, they get passed on even though you didn't tell the C compiler about that.

```
errExit:
        sub     rsp, 8
        xor     eax, eax       # Variadic functions get AL = # of args passed in XMM regs
        call    errPrint
        mov     edi, 1
        call    exit           # GCC knows exit() is noreturn
```

**If there was any code before `call errPrint`, such as a call to `strcpy`, that would of course step on those arg-passing registers.**  So they have different values when `call errPrint` runs, except for the one arg you told the C compiler about.  It will save that in a call-preserved register across a `call strcpy`.

---

If you'd compiled this for a calling convention with fewer register args, like 32-bit x86 (`gcc -m32`) where there are only stack args, the pointers that `vsnprintf` references with `%s` conversions be from `errExit`'s stack frame, above any args it intended to pass.  So probably a stack slot of padding for alignment, then in a debug build maybe a saved EBP, maybe even `errExit`'s own return address.

If you're curious, use `%p` conversions to print the pointer values instead of trying to dereference and segfaulting.

---

C doesn't have a way to specify that it should pass on only the register args; if you want to pass on an unknown number of args from a `...`, you have to do it with a `va_list` which works for any number of args, including 7 or more on x86-64 System V.  That's a good thing because some targets wouldn't have any register args, so just saving/restoring the register args would pass on 0 args.

I'm showing asm only to understand why one version happened to work, *not* as a suggestion for anything you can do to write safe and portable C that can compile to asm like this, even if there's no other work before the `call errPrint`.

Answer (score 4):

In `errExit()` you need to pass the variable arguments to another function via a `va_list` argument.  As you were not, `vsnprintf` will eventually crash trying to access non-existing arguments on the stack.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ERR_BUFFER_SIZE 4096

void verrPrint(const char *format, va_list ap) {
    char buf[ERR_BUFFER_SIZE];
    vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), format, ap);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", buf);
}

void errPrint(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    verrPrint(format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

void errExit(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    verrPrint(format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(void) {
    errPrint("What is the meaning of %s\n", "life?");
    errExit("%d\n", 42);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK,I learned it. I used to try so. I prefer to use `va_arg()`, `va_list()` .etc as less as possible because I feel unfamiliar with them. Now it seems to be impossible. Thank you!

Comment: @sixsixqaq — you can achieve your desired result, but not in the way you are trying to do it.  You need to use the auxilliary function taking the `va_list` argument directly.  Note that `va_list` is a type, not a function; `va_arg` is necessarily a function-like macro, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone.I have learned your from your answers.
I choose to change my code like below.

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ERR_BUFFER_SIZE 4096

void errPrint(const char *format, va_list arg_list)
{
    char buf[ERR_BUFFER_SIZE];
    vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), format, arg_list);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", buf);
}

void errExit(const char *format, va_list arg_list)
{
    errPrint(format, arg_list);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void v_exec(void (*func)(const char *, va_list), const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list arg_list;
    va_start(arg_list, format);

    func(format, arg_list);

    va_end(arg_list);
}

int main(void) 
{ 
    v_exec(errExit,"%s%d", "hello",520);
    return 0;
}
```